# Trying to find difference between two column values in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to find difference between two columns in a grid and show it on 3rd column. However, I get the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Here's my code so far:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issued Quantity"SortExpression="Issued_Quantity">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="txtIssued_Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("Issued_Quantity")) %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Returned Quantity" SortExpression="Return_Quantity">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="txtReturn_Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("Return_Quantity")) %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual Used Quantity" SortExpression="txtQty1">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Enabled="False" Height="27px" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Issued_Quantity")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Return_Quantity"))%>' Width="73px"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What `Eval("Return_Quantity")` and `Eval("Issued_Quantity")` returns exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Your calculation syntax seems little bit weird. Are you sure you get _right_ values for your `Convert` methods?

Comment: It will show decimal numbers from database. In database the Return_Quantity and Issued_Quantity are "NVARCHAR".

Comment: Why do you store decimals as NVARCHAR?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: actually I'm building a report page. The table and the data base has been already created by someone else.

Comment: Or is it possible to have it subtracted in the query itself and bind it on the grid. Even that would help.

Comment: try decimal.Parse(Eval("Issued_Quantity"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this..

Calculate Actual quantity in the database query itself.

```
Select Issued_Quantity, Return_Quantity, convert(decimal(4,2),Issued_Quantity) - convert(decimal(4,2),Return_Quantity) as Actual_Quantity from [YourTable]
```

Then edit your code like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual Used Quantity" SortExpression="txtQty1">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Enabled="False" Height="27px" Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("Actual_Quantity ")) %>' Width="73px"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this will help..

Note: decimal(4,2) is for indication purpose. You can change them as per actual data.

One more observation not related to this question but in general. Do not use height in px. It disturbs your UI. Try to use height in % like 20%. It keeps the formatting as per the screen size.